# Excel VBA working with current cell selection

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this is a dumb question but still fairly new to VBA.

I'm building a daily schedule sheet, and as part of it want to be able to color code high and low priority appointments. Rather than having to manually adjust the color and bold each one, I want to run a macro with a shortcut key to modify the cells I've selected.

I have the color/bold part figured out, but am having trouble telling it to apply the changes the cells I have selected. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry, the code is-

```
Sub HighPriority() 

HighPriority Macro

    Range("AE27:AP27").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Range("AE27:AP27").Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

So instead of it always editing AE27:AP27, I would want it to apply the changes to whichever cells I have selected.

Comment: Could you update your question with your current VBA code you have so we can understand your problem better?

Comment: sorry, edited my original post

Answer (score 2):

After **Select** ing your cells, run something like:

```
Sub ColorMe()
    With Selection
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That got it working with the current cell selection, just had to update it to do the font in the color I wanted.

Comment: One of the few times you might NOT [avoid using select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: @Chrismas007 I agree with you completely.....working within VBA, **Selection** should usually be avoided; but it is not a bad way to work with a Human User.